# JS - Promises executing in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuejs2, vuex

what my code is trying to do is create an array of objects that have some dynamic properties, these properties are to be filled as a result of some functions. I'm trying to make use of promises otherwise my template is rendered before the function has finished and these objects' properties will be null or undefined, causing errors in the template.

This is the first function

```
fetchUserPortfolioCoins({ commit, dispatch, state, rootGetters }) {
        const promises = []
        promises.push(dispatch('utilities/setLoading', true, { root: true })) // start loader
        if (!rootGetters['auth/isAuthenticated']) {
            // if user isn't logged, pass whatever is in the store, so apiDetails will be added to each coin
            let coins = state.userPortfolioCoins
            coins.forEach(coin => { promises.push(dispatch('createAcqCostConverted', coin)) })
            commit('SET_USER_COINS', { coins, list: 'userPortfolioCoins' })
        } else {
            // otherwise, pass the response from a call to the DB coins
            Vue.axios.get('/api/coins/').then(response => {
                let coins = response.data
                coins.forEach(coin => { promises.push(dispatch('createAcqCostConverted', coin)) })
                commit('SET_USER_COINS', { coins, list: 'userPortfolioCoins' })
            })
        }
        Promise.all(promises)
            .then(() => {
                commit('SET_USER_PORTFOLIO_OVERVIEW')
                dispatch('utilities/setLoading', false, { root: true })
            })
            .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
    },
```

that calls this one:

```
createAcqCostConverted({ dispatch, rootState }, coin) {
    const promises = []
    // this check is only going to happen for sold coins, we are adding sell_price_converted in case user sold in BTC or ETH
    if (coin.sell_currency === 'BTC' || coin.sell_currency === 'ETH') {
        const URL = `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=${coin.coin_symbol}&tsyms=${rootState.fiatCurrencies.selectedFiatCurrencyCode}&ts=${coin.sold_on_ts}`
        promises.push(Vue.axios.get(URL, {
            transformRequest: [(data, headers) => {
                delete headers.common.Authorization
                return data
            }]
        }))
    }
    // if user bought with BTC or ETH we convert the acquisition cost to the currently select fiat currency, using the timestamp
    if (coin.buy_currency === 'BTC' || coin.buy_currency === 'ETH') {
        const URL = `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=${coin.coin_symbol}&tsyms=${rootState.fiatCurrencies.selectedFiatCurrencyCode}&ts=${coin.bought_on_ts}`
        promises.push(Vue.axios.get(URL, {
            transformRequest: [(data, headers) => {
                delete headers.common.Authorization
                return data
            }]
        }))
    } else {
        // if the selected fiatCurrency is the same as the buy_currency we skip the conversion
        if (coin.buy_currency === rootState.fiatCurrencies.selectedFiatCurrencyCode) {
            coin.acquisition_cost_converted = NaN
            return coin
            // otherwise we create the acq cost converted property
        } else promises.push(dispatch('fiatCurrencies/convertToFiatCurrency', coin, { root: true }))
    }
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(response => {
            const value = response[0].data[coin.coin_symbol][rootState.fiatCurrencies.selectedFiatCurrencyCode]
            if (coin.sell_currency === 'BTC' || coin.sell_currency === 'ETH') coin.acquisition_cost_converted = value
            if (coin.buy_currency === 'BTC' || coin.buy_currency === 'ETH') coin.acquisition_cost_converted = value
            return coin
        })
        .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
},
```

The problem is that the first function is not waiting for the second one to complete. How can I adjust this code to fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Try reducing your example to a minimal self-contained one that still shows the problem. If you are lucky, doing that will be enough to let you figure out yourself what is the problem. If not, it will be much easier for others to see it and help you. See also http://www.sscce.org/ for more tips on how to reduce and produce a good example.

Comment: `createAcqCostConverted` sometimes returns `coin` (i.e. `if the selected fiatCurrency is the same as the buy_currency` - in this case, any Promise pushed to promises will be "lost") and at other times returns `undefined` ... and never returns a Promise - that Promise.all statement at the end doesn't "magically" return a promise, you need to `return Promise.all` if you want to return a promise

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for that, I was confused on where to put the return, if inside the .then() or where, this clears up some confusion.. Still the first function isn't working as expected

Comment: yes, inside the .then **as well** - and if the second function doesn't return a promise where you expect it to return a promise, then the first function (that expects a promise or a value from the second function) wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing all promises at the same time. `Promise.all` does not execute them in order. The order of the array you pass it is not relevant. It simply resolves when they all finish regardless of order.

The execution happens when you call the functions, which is before you even push them into the array.

If you need to wait for the first to finish before calling the second. You need to call the second inside the first `.then` function. For example...

```
dispatch('utilities/setLoading', true, { root: true }).then(resultOfSetLoading => {
   return Promise.all(coins.map(coin =>  dispatch('createAcqCostConverted', coin)))
}).then(resultOfCreateQcqCostConverted => {
   // all createAcqCostConverted are complete now
})
```

So now, `dispatch('utilities/setLoading')` will run first. Then, once complete, `dispatch('createAcqCostConverted')` will run once for each coin (at the same time since I used `Promise.all`).

I recommend you read up a bit more on how [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) works. It is natural to assume it resolves them in order, but it does not.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I'm adjusting a bit the first function to match what you suggested and the second one as well, apparently it needs some work too and it seems like I'm making it work somehow someway. I wanna test it out some more though...

Question: why .map and not .forEach?

Comment: I switched to map, because I am passing the result to `Promise.all`. `map` returns an array of all the values returned by its callback. `forEach` returns `undefined`. If I  had used `forEach` there, I'd be passing `undefined` to `Promise.all` instead of an array of promises

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to make it work (both for logged off user and logged in user, 2 different approaches) after I read some of you guys replies, not sure if it's the cleanest approach.

First function:

```
fetchUserPortfolioCoins({ commit, dispatch, state, rootGetters }) {
    const setCoinsPromise = []
    let coinsToConvert = null
    // start loader in template
    dispatch('utilities/setLoading', true, { root: true })
    // if user is logged off, use the coins in the state as dispatch param for createAcqCostConverted
    if (!rootGetters['auth/isAuthenticated']) setCoinsPromise.push(coinsToConvert = state.userPortfolioCoins)
    // otherwise we pass the coins in the DB
    else setCoinsPromise.push(Vue.axios.get('/api/coins/').then(response => { coinsToConvert = response.data }))

    // once the call to the db to fetch the coins has finished
    Promise.all(setCoinsPromise)
        // for each coin retrived, create the converted acq cost
        .then(() => Promise.all(coinsToConvert.map(coin => dispatch('createAcqCostConverted', coin))))
        .then(convertedCoins => {
            // finally, set the portfolio coins and portfolio overview values, and stop loader
            commit('SET_USER_COINS', { coins: convertedCoins, list: 'userPortfolioCoins' })
            commit('SET_USER_PORTFOLIO_OVERVIEW')
            dispatch('utilities/setLoading', false, { root: true })
        }).catch(err => { console.log(err) })
},
```

createAcqCostConverted function:

```
createAcqCostConverted({ dispatch, rootState }, coin) {
    const promises = []
    // this check is only going to happen for sold coins, we are adding sell_price_converted in case user sold in BTC or ETH
    if (coin.sell_currency === 'BTC' || coin.sell_currency === 'ETH') {
        const URL = `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=${coin.coin_symbol}&tsyms=${rootState.fiatCurrencies.selectedFiatCurrencyCode}&ts=${coin.sold_on_ts}`
        promises.push(Vue.axios.get(URL, {
            transformRequest: [(data, headers) => {
                delete headers.common.Authorization
                return data
            }]
        }))
    }
    // if user bought with BTC or ETH we convert the acquisition cost to the currently select fiat currency, using the timestamp
    if (coin.buy_currency === 'BTC' || coin.buy_currency === 'ETH') {
        const URL = `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricehistorical?fsym=${coin.coin_symbol}&tsyms=${rootState.fiatCurrencies.selectedFiatCurrencyCode}&ts=${coin.bought_on_ts}`
        promises.push(Vue.axios.get(URL, {
            transformRequest: [(data, headers) => {
                delete headers.common.Authorization
                return data
            }]
        }))
    } else {
        // if the selected fiatCurrency is the same as the buy_currency we skip the conversion
        if (coin.buy_currency === rootState.fiatCurrencies.selectedFiatCurrencyCode) {
            promises.push(coin.acquisition_cost_converted = NaN)
            // otherwise we create the acq cost converted property
        } else promises.push(dispatch('fiatCurrencies/convertToFiatCurrency', coin, { root: true }))
    }
    return Promise.all(promises)
        .then(response => {
            if (coin.sell_currency === 'BTC' || coin.sell_currency === 'ETH') {
                const value = response[0].data[coin.coin_symbol][rootState.fiatCurrencies.selectedFiatCurrencyCode]
                coin.acquisition_cost_converted = value
            }
            if (coin.buy_currency === 'BTC' || coin.buy_currency === 'ETH') {
                const value = response[0].data[coin.coin_symbol][rootState.fiatCurrencies.selectedFiatCurrencyCode]
                coin.acquisition_cost_converted = value
            }
            return coin
        })
        .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
},
```

In the second function I didn't have to adjust much, I just added a "return" for the Promise.all and corrected the if/else to use the response only in specific causes, because the "value" variable generated from the response is valid only in those 2 cases, in the other cases I could simply return the "coin".

Hope it makes sense, here to explain anything better if needed and/or discuss ways to make this code better (I have a feeling it's not, not sure why though :P )